# C# ImageFormat to string

Tags: c#, image

How can I obtain **human readable string**(i.e. image format itself) from *System.Drawing.ImageFormat* object?

I mean if I have **`ImageFormat.Png`** is that possible to convert it to "png" string?

**EDIT:** I see some misunderstanding here. Here is mine code:

```
Image objImage = Image.FromStream(file);

ImageFormat imFormat = objImage.RawFormat;

imFormat.ToString();
```

**It returns "`[ImageFormat: b96b3caf-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e]`" but I want "`Png`"!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ImageFormat.Png.ToString()` returns "Png"...

EDIT: OK, it seems `ToString` returns the name only for `ImageFormat` instances returned by the static properties...

You could create a lookup dictionary to get the name from the Guid:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Guid, string> _knownImageFormats =
            (from p in typeof(ImageFormat).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
             where p.PropertyType == typeof(ImageFormat)
             let value = (ImageFormat)p.GetValue(null, null)
             select new { Guid = value.Guid, Name = value.ToString() })
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Guid, p => p.Name);

static string GetImageFormatName(ImageFormat format)
{
    string name;
    if (_knownImageFormats.TryGetValue(format.Guid, out name))
        return name;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Too hard solution for C# novice. I'll better use Equals here... But thanks any way!

Comment: Great solution ! Sad though that this is not readily available in ImageFormat.

Answer (score 28):

Use the [ImageFormatConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa054ck9) class from the System.Drawing namespace:

```
this.imageInfoLabel.Text = 
    new ImageFormatConverter().ConvertToString(this.Image.RawFormat);
```

For a PNG image it returns *Png*, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

ImageFormat values are identified by Guid you need to create your own map of Guid -> Name

```
var dict = (
    from t in typeof(ImageFormat).GetProperties()
    where t.PropertyType == typeof(ImageFormat)
    let v = (ImageFormat)t.GetValue(null, new object[0])
    select new { v.Guid, t.Name }
    ).ToDictionary(g => g.Guid, g => g.Name);

string name;
if (dict.TryGetValue(ImageFormat.Png.Guid, out name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are not so many Image formats. So you can use a switch in case you want to specify your descriptions yourself or just use the

```
Imageformat.Specific.ToString()
```

(specific is the name of the specific image format)

Comment: That will not work because I have compile time reference on ImageFormat. See my edits in my origin question